# Get Virtual Desktop information using Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

**Background**
I'm trying to make an app that tells me what virtual desktop I'm on without having to go to the whole virtual desktop view. I figured my bet was to whip up a quick Electron app to toss an icon into the system tray with a tooltip that gives the current virtual desktop name. I got pretty close!

I'm pretty much using boilerplate Electron, and that's not where I'm getting stuck. I'm having trouble actually getting the names of the virtual desktops, as well as finding out which one I'm on.

I couldn't find any NPM packages for this, so unfortunately I don't have anything that I've tried that I can share. I will share what I have, though.

**Code**
`main.js`

```
const { app, Tray, Menu } = require("electron");

let tray = null;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  tray = new Tray("./assets/icons/monitor.ico");

  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: "vdName1", type: "radio" },
    { label: "vdName2", type: "radio" },
    { label: "vdName3", type: "radio", checked: true },
    { label: "vdName4", type: "radio" },
    { type: "separator" },
    { label: "Exit", role: "quit" },
  ]);

  tray.setToolTip("vdNameCurrent");
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
});
```

**TLDR**
So what's the best way to access the Virtual Desktop information from inside Node.js? Is there a package I missed? Is there a way for me to more natively query the system for information, maybe using something wrapped up in Electron?

PS: I'm realizing I only asked about getting the information about the desktop names and which is the current one, but there are actually three things I need to be able to do:

1. Access the names of all virtual desktops and the current virtual desktop
2. Change to a given virtual desktop
3. Listen for changes in the virtual desktop, so I can update the current desktop

My preferred solution would (of course) be able to do all of these, haha.

I did end up finding `winapi` as an potential solution to my problem, but I'm having trouble installing it. It seems like I've having an issue with `node-gyp`, even after trying to correctly install `windows-build-tools`.